# How to retrieve deleted work from bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have an mvc visual c# project that I've been working on. Which I cloned from my work's bitbucket's repository to my device.
I don't have any former experience with bitbucket or any of these syncing mechanisms, I'm new to all this.
Anyhow, I had tasks that my manager gave me, which is building a few views for our websites. And of course building all the models/controllers needed for it.
Now starts my problem, after a couple of weeks of work, I was doing finishing touches to my task, and by mistake I cut something instead of copying it without realizing. Then, I don't know what exactly happened or how it happened, but I ended up totally losing the piece of code I cut, which was MUCH!
So I started trying to retrieve it, but my files were saved, and that code was just gone.
So I thought, maybe there's still a copy of all of my work in this bitbucket repository's history. Maybe if I can find the history of my changes-to-files, I can go back in steps and undo my changes. Remember, I have zero experience with bitbucket. So clueless me, went on, and messed around with what's in front of my eyes... I don't know how to explain this part...
I ended up going back to the first version of the project which I initially started working on.
What I've done is there was a pull request that was made back when I started my work, and apparently I went back to that version.

So now, I lost like 17 files, 2 weeks of work.
And, I don't understand, where did my actual files go to? They are not in my recycle bin. Are they in bitbucket repository's recycle bin?
Can't I go back in time and view all my previous edits and changes to the project?
Is my work gone forever?

Btw, I'm pretty positive I completely butchered the rules of asking questions around here, I did actually try looking up solutions/answers, and apparently my only solution is to study bitbucket and try to figure out what to do...

Comment: Give us the branch names involved here, and include as many commands as you remember, which led you to this point.  Git is fairly disaster proof, insofar that you probably can just checkout an earlier version of a branch, or a commit, to get back all your work.

Comment: In general, to know where you have been, use `git reflog`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Looking at what I have here, there's only one branch (master), which contains the entire project.
Commands, I don't know how to write git commands, all I worked with or seen is UI, anyhow, there were two outgoing commits, and one incoming commit.
The one incoming commit, I think is the pull command for the project.
The outgoing commits, one of them I think was a push commit by me by mistake, and the other my colleague did of my work like a week ago.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen And what I remember doing, I was trying to look for the history of my changes, and I don't know how it came up to my mind but.. I right-clicked the incoming pull commit, and selected hard reset on it. Then Visual Studio started loading tons of files, and I was taken back to the very beginning. Tho, I was able to retrieve some of my work from the commit my colleague done..
Also, I paused my work on the project and started learning this Git stuff!

Comment: If you really did a hard reset, then you may have wiped some stuff out.  But, those deleted commits should still be present in the reflog.  Someone might be able to walk you through this.